# Why can't I see keyframes in blender after importing bvh files though it plays animation?

Tags: animation, interface, keyframes

Animation is playing but no keyframe is displayed in either timeline or graph editor.
[image: []][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMO6U.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Can you please edit your question with a more details, what research you did before to solve your problem, and embed your screenshot INTO this post (not a imgur link)? You'll get fast response then.

Comment: My first instinct is that the keyframes are in an NLA strip, but without a copy of the .blend file available from pasteall.org or http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, I can't be sure.